# Open a picture without any frame in center of screen in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

As you know in `MATLAB R2014a compiler` we can set a picture to open in center of screen before opening of main `GUI` (loading process). How can I have this functionality without using `compiler` (in `MATLAB` environment) - open a picture without any frame (only picture) in center of screen for a specific time (for example 2~3 second) and after that automatically the main `GUI` will open.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code to demonstrate how to do it:

```
clear 
clc

iptsetpref('ImshowBorder','tight'); % Tell Matlab not to show borders

ScreenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize') % Get the screen size, in the form [left bottom width height]

A = imread('peppers.png'); % sample image

% Set position of the figure in format [left bottom width height]. You want to play with this to set     the position right

hFig = figure('Position',[3*ScreenSize(3)/10 ScreenSize(4)/3 ScreenSize(3)/2 ScreenSize(4)/2]);



% Remove the menu and toolbars

 set(hFig, 'MenuBar', 'none');
 set(hFig, 'ToolBar', 'none');

hIm = imshow(A); % Display your image

pause(2) % Pause execution for 2 seconds. 

close(hFig) % Close figure

DummyGUI_2 % Open your GUI
```

**EDIT**

Well here is a link to a File Exchange submission to create splash screen;

http://www.mathworks.ca/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30508-splashscreen

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it don't remove anything in `MATLAB R2014a` ! I copied this code in a M-file and run it. Everything is normal ! I want only have a image in center of screen without any toolbar, menu and borders.

Comment: I want remove all frames and toolbars that are above window. Close,minimize,maximize etc.

Comment: Ok sorry about that I did not put the most important lines of code. Now they are in my edited answer please have a look at it.

Comment: The same problem. I only want a picture in center of screen without any frame,toolbar,menu etc. Only the picture.

Comment: I only want a picture in center of screen without any frame,menu,toolbar etc. Only a picture. The new edited code suffers from same problem. Everything is the same in `MATLAB R2014a` in `Windows 8.1`

Comment: I think we need use `java` to do that in `MATLAB`.

Comment: Yep I'm afraid so. I put a link for a File Exchange submission at the end of my above answer; it's used to create splash screens that could solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `SplashScreen` is the solution.